# Python sentry logging through OpenVPN tunnel?

Tags: python, sentry

I have sentry installed on a server 1 (which is a client of openvpn server). All traffic is directed via tunnel (to server 2) and sentry on server1 cannot log the errors in the python script to sentry.io. When I tested it from server 2 (which is also a client of openvpn server) but has access to the internet via another interface card, sentry.io is picking up the errors.

So the question is how to make sentry.io catch the errors in server 1?